# How to improve performance using WCF Service

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, performance

My scenario is : WebApp -> WCF Service ->  Oracle DB

I am using custom paging & binding gridview at client side so to avoid postback i m using webmethod in WebApp which calls a WCF method which in turn calls a Stored Procedure in Oracle .This SP returns a DataTable approx 1 MB of size. So every time when i perform any operation on a gridview it fetches 1MB of data from service which degrades application performance as i m interested only in 100 records(Paging). I can not modify the SP what is the other way available to improve the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the best solution would be to query the data in pages, but since you can't touch the stored procedure that option is not available to you. So the next best thing is to query the data once and cache the results in the ASP.NET session. That way you only hit the database once, and subsequent calls are taken from an in-memory representation of your query results.

I was able to find [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx) with pretty good coverage of using ASP.NET sessions with WCF.

Comment: What if the WCF service is not hosted in IIS/ASP.NET?

Comment: When you say that you have a webmethod that calls a WCF service, does that mean a 2 tier service layer with the front being ASMX and the middle tier WCF hosted using ServiceHost? If that's what you're doing, I would do my caching in the ASMX layer instead of the WCF layer, since you can access the ASP.NET session from there.